# Can we "go to a movie"? Is it grammatical?

Tags: colloquial-language, formality, metonymy

Please tell me, can I say "I go to a movie (I mean a film)"? Because we go to a place not to a film. I saw this sentence in "Tactics for listening":

> I went to a really dumb movie.

First of all, "movie" here refers to a film not a cinema.

1. Can we use "went" with "film"?
2. What happens if I use "go" with "film", I mean in present tense does it work?
3. Can I use it in both formal and informal context?

Comment: You can go to a doctor, a dentist, to church, to confession, to college (or university), and yes, even to a movie (or a film). The preposition *to* is a remarkably flexible little beast, for all that it's just two letters long. It's probably a figurative use in some sense, but it's a usage that has had a lot of practice over the centuries. Don't let literal-mindedness get in the way of free-flowing English.

Comment: Thank you. And I can use it in both formal and informal context?

Comment: "Went" is only the simple past of "go". **We are going to** a national conference --> **We went to** *a national conference*. Although on second thoughts, *attended* sounds better, so formality depends on the event being visited or participated.

Answer (score 0):

Language is flexible, and one (among many) flexibilities is to create meaning by *hinting* at something instead of outright saying it. This is called "figurative" meaning.

Actually, a "film" is called a "film", because historically it consisted of rolls of long celluloid strips with some pigment on it. Shine light through and the picture is projected onto a wall. Move the strip fast enough and the illusion of movement occurs. This is **not** how these things work nowadays (we have digital means of storing information), but we still call it "film".

Figurative speaking makes for simpler expressions because often the *essence* of what you want to convey can be transported in much more concise way:

> I go to Rome.

This does not necessarily mean i "go" the whole way: some part I *drive*, some part I *fly*, some part I indeed *go* and so on. Still, you get what i intended to say, yes?

For the same reason you can (and should!) say

> I saw a film

instead of

> I saw the decoding of a digitally stored MP-4 file

you can say

> I went to a movie

instead of

> I went to a specialised place where MP-4-files are decoded for a large audience.

The latter one would be technically correct and still outright ridiculous.

Comment: Thank you for helpful explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually use "I went to see a movie" or "I went to a movie theatre", but the earlier speakers are right in that it is grammatically correct.

Usage Notes: Movie is used in North America, while film is used elsewhere. North Americans normally use film as a verb (the video was filmed yesterday) or in reference to the physical material that movies were stored on (this uses 5-millimeter film).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for sharing your idea.